# Ionic3 Angular not allows to access local video file from video player (Android & iOS)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, videogular

I have an issue (it seems to be hard, I've searched a lot and not found any working solution) with Ionic 3.

### Summary of issue

- Trying to access local video file: `'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/br.com.myapp/files/916354762.mp4'`

### Steps I need to do

- Load .mp4 files from web (using XHR blob) and write then on local data directory. (works well)
- Play the video in app with HTML5 or the other player. (not works)

### Detailed description

My app (android & ios) will work with offline video. First, I've downloaded the videos to the device, using a File native plugin and this step is nice, I can write and recover the file, all with success. But when I need to load and play the video on HTML5 video player, or with videogular2(http://videogular.github.io/videogular2), the video isn't loading... The videogular2 returns an error `'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/br.com.myapp/files/916354762.mp4'`, and the HTML5 player isn't returning any error.

### What i've tried and didn't work:

- Use HTML5 video player
- Use videogular2
- Read the video file as `base64 string` (works well, i can get base64 correctly), but it's large file (>20MB) and the app dies.
- Set `allow-origin file://*/` on `config.xml` file.

### HTML5 video player code:

html

```
<video #video controls autoplay></video>
```

ts

```
@ViewChild('video') videoPlayer: ElementRef;
...
let video = this.videoPlayer.nativeElement;
video.src = 'file:///data/user/0/br.com.myapp/files/916354762.mp4';
or
video.src = '/data/user/0/br.com.myapp/files/916354762.mp4'; // i've tried also without file://, also not works, i also tried with DomSanitizer
video.play();
```

### VIDEOGULAR2 code:

html

```
<vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
    ...
    <video #media
           [vgMedia]="media"
           [src]="src"
           id="singleVideo"
           preload="auto"
           crossorigin>
    </video>
  </vg-player>
```

ts

```
video.src = 'file:///data/user/0/br.com.myapp/files/916354762.mp4';
or
video.src = '/data/user/0/br.com.myapp/files/916354762.mp4';
```

Please, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by using this native plugin:

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/

This is the example of my short, working-well function:

```
    playFile() {
    this.fileOpener.open("file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20190103_143837.mp4", "video/mp4")
      .then(() => console.log("File is opened"))
      .catch(e => console.log("Error opening file", e));
  }
```